# Bind M-x and ESC-x to separate functions

Tags: key-bindings

Is it possible to bind `left Alt-x` (currently evaluates as `M-x`) and `escape key-x` to **separate** functions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to customize `meta-prefix-char` to <kbd>C-z</kbd>, which redirects the translation from Alt/Meta to ESC-as-prefix to <kbd>C-z</kbd> instead. You can then make bindings for <kbd>M-x</kbd>  separately:

```
(define-prefix-command 'ctrl-z-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'ctrl-z-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x k") #'kill-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remap the command bound those keys (which is `execute-extended-command`) to another key. To bind all keys bound to `execute-extended-command` to `forward-char` instead, for example:

```lisp
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] #'forward-char)
```

Comment: Edited question. Changed "different" to "separate".

Comment: Well, you completely changed the meaning of the question by doing that. Now you're apparently asking to have `M-x` and `ESC x` be bound to two different commands - something very different. Please don't do that. Post a separate question for a different question. And next time, show what you've tried, or give an example of what you want: "I want `M-x` to be bound to `foobar` and `ESC x` to be bound to `toto`.

Comment: You also didn't change the question title. It still says "different function". And note that "function" is singular - it clearly says that you want both of those to be bound to a (single) different command.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. Forgot the `s` on `function`.

Comment: You posed a different question originally, which I then answered. You should restore the question you actually posed - whether or not you meant to pose it, and then post a separate question to ask what you really intended to ask, which is something completely different. Don't change the meaning of the question just because you expressed yourself wrong. Another alternative is to delete this question and then post what you really meant to ask.

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote?